# Navigate to other component but maintain link, only add /notifications on current llink - with Stackblitz

Tags: angular, angular-routing

How can I route to the another module child component?

I have Core module where I hold NavBar component. From NavBar component, on click to one of the links I should redirect user to the Notifications component from Core Module. But I need to define the url as /profesor/notifications

NavBar component:

```
 <li><a routerLink="/profesor/notifications"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Notifications </a></li>
```

I don't have any defined route in NavBar routing module.

In app-routing.module

```
  { path: 'profesor', component: ProfesorHomeComponent },
```

In profesor-routing.module

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ProfesorHomeComponent },
  { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent },
];
```

What am I doing wrong?

StackBlitz: Now there is Stackblitz so if you can check it out. But please only add /profesor to the link and then try to navigate to profesor/notifications

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vdytbz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofesor%2Fprofesor.module.ts

Answer (score 1):

Notifications are not a child of the professor module. to fix this, move notifications to the children routes

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: ProfesorHomeComponent , 
 children : [
  { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent }]},
];
```

and inside ProfesorHomeComponent HTML template include router-outlet to render the children components

```html
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

---

or you can call the notifications directly if the module is not a lazyload

```
 <li><a routerLink="/notifications"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i> Notifications </a></li>
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. Still, on click to a link, it redirects me to / page. Note that NavBar is in different module than Notifications component. Based on this answer, I added children component in profesor-routing.module as you described and called it from NavBar component with routerLink. Didn't work

Comment: I edited the question. Also now there is Stackblitz so if you can check it out. But please only add /profesor to the link and then try to navigate to Notifications. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vdytbz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofesor%2Fprofesor.module.ts

Comment: Also I don't need it to be children component.. I just need to add /notifications on current link

Comment: include notification notifications in app-router
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'profesor', component: ProfesorHomeComponent },
  { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent },
];

Answer (score 0):

Here how I have done it. The nav bar looks something like this:

```
 <a [routerLink]="['/main', { outlets: { c: ['dashboard'] } }]">
      Dashboard </a>
    
 <a [routerLink]="['/main', { outlets: { c: ['membership'] } }]">
       Memberships </a>
    
 <a [routerLink]="['/main', { outlets: { c: ['client'] } }]">
      Clients </a>
```

and the routing module is:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main', component: MainComponent, children: [
      {path:'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent, outlet: 'c'},
      {path:'membership', component: MembershipComponent, outlet: 'c'},
      { path: 'client', component: ClientComponent, outlet: 'c' },
    ]},
];
```

Then inside the main component:

```
<router-outlet name="c"></router-outlet>
```

If you need more explination please let me know.

Comment: I  edited the question. Also now there is Stackblitz so if you can check it out. But please only add /profesor to the link and then try to navigate to Notifications: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vdytbz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fprofesor%2Fprofesor.module.ts

Comment: Dear I checked your project. You have made the project unnesserly complicated. You dont need the profesor-routing-module  and core-routing-module while you have app-routing module! also you dont need profesor.module and core.module while you can use app.module!